# french quote for blockquote and italics foreignquote

Tags: polyglossia, quoting, csquotes, french

I try to generate a correct `blockquote` and `foreignblockquote` which start with `«` and end with `»`

What i already have :

> « Test in french » (citation)
>
> « *Test in english* » (citation)

What i want with blockquote/foreignblockquote :

> « Test
>    in
>    french » (citation)
>
> «*Test
>
>   in
>
>   english* » (citation)

Here the mwe :

```
% !TEX encoding =  UTF-8 Unicode
% -*- program: xelatex -*-
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt,twoside, openright]{memoir}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{french}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage[variant=ancient]{greek}
\setotherlanguage{latin}
\usepackage[autostyle=true,french=guillemets,maxlevel=3]{csquotes}
%% QUOTE FRENCH ITALICS
\renewcommand{\mktextquote}[6]{%
  #1%
  \iflanguage{english}{\itshape}{}% ADDED
  #2#4#3#6#5%
}

\renewcommand{\mkblockquote}[4]{%
  \iflanguage{english}{\itshape}{}% ADDED
  #1#2#3#4%
}

\DeclareQuoteStyle{english}
  {\mkfrenchopenquote{\guillemotleft}\itshape}
  {\itshape\mkfrenchclosequote{\guillemotright}}
  {\textquotedblleft\itshape}
  {\itshape\textquotedblright}

\begin{document}

    \enquote{Test in french}

    \blockquote{Test \\ in \\ french}

    \foreignquote{english}{Test in english}

    \foreignblockquote{english}{Test \\ in \\ english}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could the package `dirtytalk` help? See the article http://texnical-designs.com/quotation-marks-and-the-latex-dirtytalk-package/

Comment: Not really related to the `memoir` class..

Comment: And your problem is with multi-line quotes. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes block quote with italics don't work... i update the text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `english` quote style swarms with `\itshape`s that catch everything but the opening quotation mark. This is bizarre, and it's also making the conditionals you use redundant.

I'm probably missing some point about your use case. However, here is some leaner code that solves your problem:

```
\usepackage[autostyle,maxlevel=3]{csquotes}

\renewcommand{\mkblockquote}[4]{%
  \openautoquote#1\closeautoquote#2#3#4} % <--------- HERE IS THE FIX

\DeclareQuoteStyle{english}
  {\itshape\mkfrenchopenquote{\guillemotleft}}
  {\mkfrenchclosequote{\guillemotright}}
  {\textquotedblleft}
  {\textquotedblright}
```

The crucial part is the renewal of `\mkblockquote` where I introduced `\openautoquote` and `\closeautoquote` around `#1`.